# Xml Path how to read property name

Tags: c#, xml, hibernate, xml-parsing

i need some help. i've got xml like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and i want to read property NAME  and value (value is between

i have done something like this

```
XPathNodeIterator iterator = nav.Select("/nh:hibernate-configuration/nh:session-factory/nh:property/@name", manager);
XPathNodeIterator iterator2 = nav.Select("/nh:hibernate-configuration/nh:session-factory/nh:property", manager);

while (iterator.MoveNext() && iterator2.MoveNext())
{
    var name = iterator.Current.Value;
    var property = iterator2.Current.Value;
}
```

but it is possible to have only one iterator in that case which i could use to get name and property ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use only the 2nd iterator and use `GetAttribute()` to read `name` attribute value :

```
XPathNodeIterator iterator2 = nav.Select("/nh:hibernate-configuration/nh:session-factory/nh:property", manager);
while (iterator2.MoveNext())
{
    var navigator = iterator.Current;
    var name = navigator.GetAttribute("name","");
    var property = navigator.Value;
}
```

Anyway, the entire task can be much simpler using `XmlDocument`, or using LINQ-to-XML as demonstrated below :

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("path_to_your_xml.xml");
XNamespace d = "urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2";
foreach(var prop in doc.Descendants(d+"property")
{
    var name = (string)prop.Attribute("name");
    var property = (string)prop;
}
```